# Pytest - Rerun complete test Module , TestClass in case of failure

Tags: python, pytest

I want leverage facility of pytest to rerun failed test cases.

However instead of running the single test. I want to run the tests inside complete Class/Module in case single test is failed inside that module. Please suggest how we can do it using 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cache or any other pytest plugin

Regards,
Shubhra Goyal

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-rerunfailures

Comment: This also supports running individual test. In my case I want to run the complete Tests inside a Class in case anyone of the test fails.

Comment: I want to run complete module in case of failure of one test cases. Tried Pytest cache plugin but it does not have facility to re run complete module in case of failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-run Failed Test and set re-tries for python3 py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894691/how-to-re-run-failed-test-and-set-re-tries-for-python3-py-test)

Comment: The question if I understand is to get similar functionality to `pytest --lf` or `pytest --ff` but rather than re-running individual tests, it re-runs the entire test class or module of which one or more tests had failed.

Comment: @MaxV how is that a duplicate? the question is clearly asking for ability to run the WHOLE test , is it that hard to distinguish?